# GooglePlay says device isn't compatible, but developers console shows it as a compatible

Tags: android

When I look at my Google Play Developers console the application is shown as compatible with device Nexus 7.

[image]

I don't have any `<uses-feature>` in my Android Manifest that would alter the device, not compatible.

The problem is that I cannot find the app on the app store and when I go to it via direct link it tells me the device isn't compatible.

Why is there a conflict between the Google Play Dev Console and the Google Play Store information?

Here is the part of my AndroidManifest content

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="xxx.xxx" >
<!--This allows the app to be installed on external memory like the SD card-->
android:installLocation="auto"

<!-- For push norifications -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<permission android:name="xxx.xxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="xxx.xxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Part of gradle content:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 10
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Also tried to install the app directly on the device but its response is: app not installed.

Comment: can you please post a part of your manifest file?

Comment: Maybe it can be for `Android version`? What's the Android version on your nexus 7?

Comment: The tablet runs on Android 6.0.1. My app min sdk is set to 16 so there shouldn't be any conflicts there.

Comment: is there no extra code inside your menifest file except **<application>** and **<uses-permission>**?

Comment: @RahulSharma correct!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please add below code in your manifest. It may be due to you did not mention the screen size that it is compatible for large screens as well.

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Also you have added this permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />`
so add this as well

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
```

It worked for me. Try it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs due to some of the package that have depended on lower SDK version and you must have added the range version for that in example:

android:minSdkVersion="16"
android:maxSdkVersion="17"

Due to this for such case remove that range version look for the alternative approach to build